# How could I match the following inside a string using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to find a model number from the following meta tag from an html document

```
<meta name="description" content="Model AB-1234. Model description here" />
```

I would like to match the model number only (`AB-1234`). I have tried several things and I will included 2 below:

```
preg_match('/<meta name="description" content="\bmodel\b(.*)"/i', $html, $model);
```

This one returns `AB-1234. Model description here`

==================================================================================

```
preg_match('/<meta name="description" content="(.*)"/i', $html, $model);
```

And this one returns: `Model AB-1234. Model description here`

Probably one way to do it is to stop right at the `.`(dot), but I have not idea how to approach that.

Thank you,

Comment: is there always a dot after the model name?

Comment: Can there be multiple model numbers? If not, why did you tag `preg-match-all`?

Comment: Sure Barmar, if you think no one that knows preg_match_all can help I will untag it.. no problem at all. I just thought they were related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '<meta name="description" content="Model AA-1234. Model description here" />

<meta name="description" content="Model AB-1234. Model description here" />

<meta name="description" content="Model AC-1234. Model description here" />

<meta name="description" content="Model AD-1234. Model description here" />
';

preg_match_all('/content="Model (.*?)\./is', $str, $data);
if(!empty($data[1])){
$models = $data[1];
print_r($models);
}
```

**// result**

```
Array ( [0] => AA-1234 [1] => AB-1234 [2] => AC-1234 [3] => AD-1234 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
preg_match('/<meta name="description" content="model\s++\K[^.]++/i',
           $html, $model);
print_r($model);
```

explanations:

```
/<meta name="description" content="model
\s++    # one or more spaces, tabs, newlines (possessive)
\K      # reset the pattern begining
[^.]++  # all that is not a dot one or more times (possessive)
```

more informations about [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

note that it is safer to extract the attribute content with the DOM and then use a regex to find the model. Example:

```
$html = <<<LOD
<meta name="description" content="Model AB-1234. Model description here" />
LOD;

$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$content=$doc->getElementsByTagName('meta')->item(0)->getAttribute('content');

preg_match('/model\s++\K[^.]++/i', $content, $model);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/<meta name="description" content="model\s+([^.]*)"/i', $html, $model);
```

In general, it's best not to use regexp to parse HTML, since you're very sensitive to the exact layout. Better is to use a DOM parsing library. Extract the `content` attribute and then you can use a regexp to extract pieces of that.